# array becamed nulled in the class

Tags: php

hay
my class

```
class language{

    function merge($filename = ''){ 
// the path is true
    return include_once ('language/'.$filename);
    }

}
```

ok this lang test

```
en.php

<?php

if (empty($lang) || !is_array($lang))
{
    $lang = array();
}

$lang = array_merge($lang, array(
    'test'      => 'Home Page'

));

?>
```

if i add

```
echo $lang['test'];
```

in the en.php its return Home Page

but i i make the class

```
$l = new language;
$l->merge('en.php');
```

its not working
i checked it

```
var_dump($lang);
```

it return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to return something from an `include_once` call you have to return something in the file. See [Example 5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

```
<?php // return.php
    $var = 'PHP';
    return $var;
?>
```

vs.

```
<?php // noreturn.php
     $var = 'PHP';
?>
```

gives

```
<?php
    $foo = include 'return.php';
    echo $foo; // prints 'PHP'

    $bar = include 'noreturn.php';
    echo $bar; // prints 1
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$lang` variables does not exist because you're including the en.php file at the scope of the merge function. From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)…

> When a file is included, the code it
>   contains inherits the variable scope
>   of the line on which the include
>   occurs. Any variables available at
>   that line in the calling file will be
>   available within the called file, from
>   that point forward. However, all
>   functions and classes defined in the
>   included file have the global scope.

Hence `$lang` is lost when `merge` returns, unless you declare it global in that function.

Answer (score 0):

see my soultion

```
function __construct(){ 
$this->lang =  array();
}

class language{

    function merge($filename = ''){     
include_once ('language/'.$filename);

    return $this->lang = $lang;
    }

}
```

and when use
echo $l->lang['test'];